# What is the best target=_parent alternative?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two views on a page, a slideshow view, and a grid view. Each slide has a hash associated with it in slideshow view. In grid view, a display of all the links associated with each slide are present. If you click on it, it should take you back to that slide and reload the page. `target="_parent"` seems to work, but it is only supported in IE. `target="_blank"` works but I need to avoid opening in a new window since it should just reload the page you are on except take you to that specific hash. Any alternatives to `target="_parent"`?

EXAMPLE: http://bigredsun.staging.wpengine.com/our-work-index/

Comment: So you're trying to use the `target` attribute to force the browser to (re)load the page when only the hash part has changed?

Comment: Essentially, however doing a force reload doesn't necessarily work because it will reload the page with the last hash that the slide was on. I basically want to reload the page with the new hash like so                   <a href="http://bigredsun.staging.wpengine.com/our-work-index/#<?php echo the_slug(); ?>" target="_parent">

Comment: window.location.hash doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see the `Page loaded. #[1-5]` in the console when you click the links:

```
<a href="#1">Test #1</a><br/>
<a href="#2">Test #2</a><br/>
<a href="#3">Test #3</a><br/>
<a href="#4">Test #4</a><br/>
<a href="#5">Test #5</a>

window.addEventListener('load', function load(){
    console.log('Page loaded.', location.hash);

    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].addEventListener('click', function click(){
            window.location = this.href;
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
    }
});
```

jsFiddle seems to have a problem with it not being a POST, so no live demo.